# How to start network interface from shell in Fedora 14/15?

Tags: networking, fedora

I need to start network interface from command line.I usually do it with the GUI but I don't have desktop manager now.I tried `/etc/init.d/network start` ,it shows ok,but when I try curl or links,it can't connect.

Answer (score 3):

Can you post `/etc/sysconfig/network`?

It may be as simple as:

```
ifup eth0
```

Fedora 15 uses "Consistent" device naming, which means that your actual device name will likely be something along the lines of em1 or pci3p1 [Source](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ConsistentNetworkDeviceNaming)

Comment: it worked but it was pci4p1 not eth0.(Fedora 15).I have no idea why.

Comment: @Alexander http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ConsistentNetworkDeviceNaming

Comment: Ugh. "Consistent" network device naming. Consistent with absolutely no other distribution, that's what.

Comment: Hyppy,can you add the link in the answer for anybody else using Fedora 15

Answer (score 2):

In Fedora there is a service called NetworkManager.service that automatically makes sure you are connected to the internet as defined in: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1`

Run this command as root to check the status of this service:

```
systemctl status NetworkManager.service
```

If it is disabled, enable it, or find out why it was disabled:

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
```

Then either reboot the computer or restart the network.service manually:

```
systemctl restart network.service
```

Here is the contents of my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1`

```
UUID="e1a84d44-b53c-43ef-a8b4-df5ce5263ebc"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
HWADDR="A8:50:F2:E2:05:7E"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEVICE="em1"
ONBOOT="yes"
USERCTL="yes"
```

You would roll your own 'restart network' scripts only if the available ones are non functional or are not adequate for a specific task.

Source:

http://danielgibbs.co.uk/2012/06/fedora-17-set-static-ip-address/